# How to see how many times a number can go into another number?

Tags: lua

I found some other responses but they are for different languages and I am very confused please help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to know how often number a fits into number b you divide b by a. that's simple math.

Answer (score 1):

The Lua `//` operator is the integer floor operation.

```
% lua
Lua 5.4.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> 10 // 3
3
>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for lua 5.1 any other possible solutions?

Comment: @d2wn if you not using 5.4 you can just do `10 / 3` if you want the result floored then do `math.floor(10 / 3)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how often a fits into b:

```
local result = b / a
```

If you're interested in an integer result you usually use the floor of that quotient.

```
local result = math.floor(b/a)
```

or you format a string, but that's kindof sense-less.

```
local result = tonumber(string.format("%.0f", b/a))
```

or you implement your own solution.

or for Lua >= 5.3 you can use the floor division operator `//`

```
local result = b // a
```